# Strategies for Integrating Youtube in a Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video, youtube, gdata-api

I'm diving into Rails 3 for the first time to build a web app that involves users uploading video. I want to offload the costs of hosting and streaming video to YouTube, but I don't know the best way to move forward with this part of the functionality.

I see two directions I can go in:

*Easier to manage approach:* Let the users upload videos to their own YouTube account via my Rails app or through YouTube, and then give the users the option to "Upload" or "Specify Video URL" in the HTML form. The downside is users have to setup and manage their own YouTube accounts, which most people don't already do.

*Better usability approach:* Create a single YouTube account, owned and maintained by me, and only give users the ability to upload video via my web app to that YouTube account.  This makes it easier for users to upload video since they don't need a YouTube account, improving the usability of my app.  The downside is, the YouTube account will have to be managed, the YouTube limits will be reached quicker (meaning I'll have to delete older videos often), among other downsides.

1. Logging in and uploading videos (using either approach), would you use an existing Gem or write your own Rails 3 code to interact directly with the YouTube API?
2. Are there other video hosting services you would consider using besides YouTube?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: have you read YouTube TOS and considered if they would allow such behavior with their platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little Google search turned out a [Rails plugin](https://github.com/edgarjs/youtube-model/tree) that uses Google AuthSub with YouTube so to answer your first question, I don't think it's necessary to rewrite code (Don't reinvent the wheel ;))

Regarding the usability direction, I think it depends on the webapp you'll be building. Is it a social app where user profiles are important? If so, I'd go with the first approach. Is it a corporate app with tutorials for employees? The second approach would work better, in my opinion.

**EDIT:**

Here's another [Youtube Gem](https://github.com/tmm1/youtube-g/tree/) which, according to the author last commit, should have compatibility with Ruby 1.9

Comment: thanks, bruno077. i actually gave that plugin a try a few days back while investigating this topic and right off the bat i was seeing breakage when following the steps exactly, so we'll see, but it seems like most of the youtube gems and plugins out there aren't very mature, or abandoned.  Also, to answer your followup question, my app is indeed social and profiles are important. that said, can I ask what are some reasons you feel the first approach is better suited? thanks again!

Comment: This is my opinion, so take it with a grain of salt. The reason I feel the first approach is better for social websites is 'ego' and personalization. In social websites, Individualism is important, and a shared YouTube account for all profiles goes against that. Besides, when I sign up for your website, I may already have a Google Account so I'd probably want to have my videos available in my existing account.

I don't know if it would be possible, and if it is, it would probably be hard to code, but perhaps you could offer both options for users who don't have or wouldn't want a Goog Account.

Comment: I found a gem which should work with Ruby 1.9 (hence with Rails 3), check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There's another good gem for this now:
https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

It's incredibly simple to use -- I'd give it a try if the others are failing you.